# Training a custom many-to-one RNN in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I'm implementing a custom RNN using tensorflow 2, for which I've written a model that takes an indefinite number of time steps and takes the outputs of the last hidden layer for all of the time steps and applies some Dense layers to it.

Now, my dataset consists in a set of training examples with shape `[28207, 8, 2]` (28207 training examples, 8 time steps, 2 features) and my output is a matrix with shape `[28207, 2]` (28207 training exmaples, 2 features) but I get the following error when training the model:

```
Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: (then a lot of 8's)
y sizes: (then a lot of 2's)
```

I've tryied expanding the dimensions of the set of labels to `[28207, 1, 2]` with no success and google has not yet helped much.

Is it even possible to perform this many-to-one implementation in tf2?

I'm using anaconda with python 3.6.12, windows 10, tensorflow 2.4.0. The cell, the model and the training code is this:

```
class RNNCell(keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
    self.units = units
    self.state_size = units
    super(TrayectoryRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # i computation
    self.Wxi = self.add_weight(name='Wxi', shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.Whi = self.add_weight(name='Whi', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.Wci = self.add_weight(name='Wci', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.bi = self.add_weight(name='bi', shape=(self.units, ), initializer="zeros", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)

    # f computation
    self.Wxf = self.add_weight(name='Wxf', shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.Whf = self.add_weight(name='Whf', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.Wcf = self.add_weight(name='Wcf', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.bf = self.add_weight(name='bf', shape=(self.units, ), initializer="zeros", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)

    # c computation
    self.Wxc = self.add_weight(name='Wxc', shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.Whc = self.add_weight(name='Whc', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.bc = self.add_weight(name='bc', shape=(self.units, ), initializer="zeros", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)

    # o computation
    self.Wxo = self.add_weight(name='Wxo', shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.Who = self.add_weight(name='Who', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.Wco = self.add_weight(name='Wco', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="random_normal", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)
    self.bo = self.add_weight(name='bo', shape=(self.units, ), initializer="zeros", regularizer=customL2Regularizer)

def call(self, inputs, states):
    # It expects two inputs: the X and the previous h
    i = tf.math.sigmoid(K.dot(inputs[0], self.Wxi) + K.dot(inputs[1], self.Whi) + K.dot(states[0], self.Wci) + self.bi)
    f = tf.math.sigmoid(K.dot(inputs[0], self.Wxf) + K.dot(inputs[1], self.Whf) + K.dot(states[0], self.Wcf) + self.bf)
    c = f * states[0] + i * tf.math.tanh(K.dot(inputs[0], self.Wxc) + K.dot(inputs[1], self.Whc) + self.bc)
    o = tf.math.sigmoid(K.dot(inputs[0], self.Wxo) + K.dot(inputs[1], self.Who) + K.dot(c, self.Wco) + self.bo)
    return o * tf.tanh(c), c
```

The network:

```
rnn_hidden_units = 128
rnn_hidden_layers = 2
lstm_outputs = []

# Inputs: [None, time_steps, 2]
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(time_steps, 2), name='inputs')

# First hidden layer previous h: [None, time_steps, 2]
zeros_placeholder = tf.fill(tf.stack([tf.shape(inputs)[0], time_steps, rnn_hidden_units]), 0.0, name='zeros_placeholder')

# First hidden layer: inputs, zeros_placeholder => [None, time_steps, rnn_hidden_units]
last_hidden_output = RNN(RNNCell(rnn_hidden_units), return_sequences=True, name='first_rnn_layer')((inputs, zeros_placeholder))

# Append last output to a list
lstm_outputs.append(last_hidden_output[:, -1, :])

# The rest of the hidden layers
for l in range(rnn_hidden_layers - 1):
    last_hidden_output = RNN(RNNCell(rnn_hidden_units), return_sequences=True, name='{}_rnn_layer'.format(l+1))((inputs, last_hidden_output))
    lstm_outputs.append(last_hidden_output[:, -1, :])

# Compute p_t+1 (assuming Y is the sigmoid function): [None, 5]
p = tf.sigmoid(OutputLayer(rnn_hidden_units)(tf.stack(lstm_outputs)))

# Compute (mu, sigma, rho): [None, 5]
output = OutputLayer(5, include_bias=False)(p)

# Define the model
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
```

The code that fails:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, rho=0.95), loss=bivariate_loss_function, metrics=['val_loss'])

# Define the Keras TensorBoard callback.
logdir="./logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

# Train the model.
model.fit(training_examples,
          training_labels,
          batch_size=64,
          epochs=5,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Comment: Why not post your error logs ?

Comment: @DachuanZhao Because it's too long for the body of the question

Comment: @YamilEssus You need to post the lines you think are relavant.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a problem of the input, since it was a list and not a numpy array.